# How to properly pass address to google geocoding service

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm getting some problems trying Google Geocoding service when using special characters like "º" or letters with accents.

Whenever I try something like:
"barcelona, nº 10"

I get 0 results. But trying:
"barcelona n 10"

I get results...

I suspect is something related with encoding.
I tried this:

```
geocoder.geocode({'address': encodeURI( $('#direction').val() )}, function(){} );
```

But didn't help.

Any Idea?

Comment: have you tried encodeURIComponent for ,

Comment: is your page in utf-8? "barcelona, nº 10" should work. it works here http://platz.se/

Comment: yes, but that makes me thing if the javascript file needs to be in utf-8 too...